# not open magento dashboard login panel after successfully install

Tags: content-management-system, magento2

I am install magento latest version and it install successfully but my problem is when i am try to open the dashboard then no one error but not show login panel like images https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjDxV.jpg it show blank like image

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question on this site. I fyou want some people to spend time to help you, you need to provide them with a well written question, as well as minimal example and your research so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on Magento 2.3.0, this happened to me the other day ?

It looks like it's a bug with:

`#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:138`

Change line 138 from: `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);`

to:

`$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`

*Please Note*
- This is just a temporary fix to make it work on your local Windows machine, don't commit or push any of this code to production as it is editing the core files (not recommended)

Comment: in the file at 114 line is  "$filename = str_replace('\\', '/', $filename);" but your line is not present in this same file, sorry

Comment: What version of Magento are you on

Comment: Magento-CE-2.3.0-2018-11-27-10-23-08

Comment: This is now a seperate problem, please select this as the right answer and ask a new question. Thanks

Comment: No problem, please accept this as correct answer if it solved you problem (green tick)